# Trying to install fails

Tags: 14.04

I am having a hard time trying to install and run 14.04. I have tried to do a dual boot. Fail. So I thought maybe it was because my system had to many drives installed. So I removed 2 drives and only SATA cdrom and SATA drive remain. Tried again with second install both showing they install but not able to access a boot menu. So removed the Hd. Installed a 40 gig as master set to see Rom first. Installed. Once formatted and installs complete the computer couldn't see the drive. So I took a old server 2000 HD installed it and this time says. "Reboot and select proper Boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key". Driving me insane. About ready to install something different.

Thanks in advance. 
James

Comment: most of the time, you have the option of a boot menu at startup. each model is different. sometimes you press f11 sometimes f12 etc. do you have this option?

Comment: Thank you for the reply... I can change to access different drives. I can access f10, escape delete f8 and so on. None give me boot options.

Comment: Well after I have tried to do everything that I can think of to run a dual boot system. I figured it was time to try something different. So I took my older 15" Compaq V5000 and installed it on there. IT isn't the fastest machine, Not a whole lot of Ram but it does work well. I have installed a few after market packages on the laptop and they seem to run rather well. It couldn't even run with the Win 7 that It was last running. Now works perfect. SO Now I just need to work out a few things to figure out how to get my Desktop disk space back from the 2 failed installs.